# Tournament and League Rules For Dominion

Tags: dominion, tournament

Where can I find official tournament and league rules for Dominion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are intentionally no official tournament rules for Dominion.

There is a [long, meandering discussion of tournament rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/457599/discussion-on-a-universal-tournament-format-for-do/page/1) for Dominion on BGG.

I was pretty happy with the tournament rules used for Dominion at the [2010 World Boardgaming Championship.](http://www.boardgamers.org/yearbook/dompge.htm)  Two things that it got right were

- An emphasis on game **placement** rather than points per game to determine advancers
- Playing two games per round and **reversing** seating order between games

But don't expect anything near consensus on the best tournament rules for Dominion.